# last given value before a specific date from a JSONB-column

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I want to get the last given value before a specific date(in this case 2015-09-30) from a BD with on id and 2 JSONB-column that looks like this:

```
1, 
[
    {"value": 4290, "time": "2014-05-15T05:31:45.077483Z"}, 
    {"value": 3490, "time": "2014-09-02T04:32:32.094733Z"}, 
    {"value": 3690, "time": "2015-01-16T04:32:28.679849Z"}, etc...
    ],
[
    {"stock_status": "instock", "time": "2014-06-15T05:31:45.077483Z"}, 
    {"stock_status": "outofstock", "time": "2014-07-02T04:32:32.094733Z"}, 
    {"stock_status": "instock", "time": "2015-01-26T04:32:28.679849Z"}, etc...
    ],
2, 
[
    {"value": 4598, "time": "2013-05-15T05:31:45.077483Z"}, 
    {"value": 3456, "time": "2014-04-02T04:32:32.094733Z"}, 
    {"value": 4354, "time": "2015-06-16T04:32:28.679849Z"}, etc...
    ]
[
    {"stock_status": "outofstock", "time": "2014-06-15T05:31:45.077483Z"}, 
    {"stock_status": "instock", "time": "2014-07-02T04:32:32.094733Z"}, 
    {"stock_status": "outofstock", "time": "2015-01-26T04:32:28.679849Z"}, etc...
    ]
```

The query I'm after should give;

- Id
- First value before date
- if the first stock_status before date = "instock"

But I can't get the timestamps right, it gives back all values before the date if any stock_status is "instock". My Query:

```
SELECT sph.id, elem1->>'value', elem1->>'time'
    FROM table as sph,
    jsonb_array_elements(sph.value_column) as array1(elem1),
    jsonb_array_elements(sph.stock_status_coulmn) as array2(elem2)

        where elem1 = (select elem1
    where elem1->> 'time'  <= '2015-09-30' and elem2->> 'time'  <= '2015-09-30' and elem2->>'stock_status' = 'instock'
order by elem1->>'time' desc
limit 1);
```

I want this to give me only one result back from the db-exemple above, the one with id 1.

Any tips? This have drived me crazy in a couple of days now...

Comment: What do you mean by half last and half first.

Comment: @FahadAnjum I mean that half of the results is right with the last dates and half takes the first dates, eg if the jsonb is `[{"value": 4290, "time": "2014-05-15T05:31:45.077483Z"}, 
{"value": 3490, "time": "2014-09-02T04:32:32.094733Z"}]` and another is `[{"value": 3490, "time": "2014-09-02T04:32:32.094733Z"}, 
{"value": 3690, "time": "2015-01-16T04:32:28.679849Z"}]` the result is `"2014-09-02T04:32:32.094733Z"`(right) and `"2014-09-02T04:32:32.094733Z"`(wrong, should be "2015-01-16T04:32:28.679849Z").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inn the end I solved it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (sph.id) sph.id, elem1->>'value' as value, elem1->>'time' as time, elem2->>'stock_status' as stock_status
    FROM table as sph
    join table2 as sp on sph.id = sp.id,
    jsonb_array_elements(sph.value_column) as array1(elem1),
    jsonb_array_elements(sph. stock_status_coulmn) as array2(elem2)

    WHERE elem1#>>'{time}' <= '2015-09-30' and elem2#>>'{time}' <= '2015-09-30'
ORDER BY sph.id, elem1#>>'{time}' DESC, elem2#>>'{time}' DESC;
```

Then I sorted away the rows that was outofstock and with the wrong value in my code(elixir) instead, not sure it's the best method but works for me anyway. :)